# How do i find the index of a string in Golfscript?

Tags: esoteric-languages, golfscript

Given a string "ABCDE", how do i find the index of occurrence of another string "C" in Golfscript?

? operator doesn't seem to work (http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html#?):

> "C" "ABCDE" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"C""ABCDE".,,@`@`{@>1$,<=}++?
```

There's no way that `"C" "ABCDE" ?` would work - if that did a string search, it would be looking for the first occurrence of `ABCDE` in `C`.

However, in GolfScript strings are really a different presentation of arrays of integers. `"ABCDE"67?` gives `2` because 67 is the Unicode codepoint for `C`.

One slightly nicer approach which you might expect to work but doesn't is (X)

```
"C""ABCDE".,,\`{>1$,<}+%\?
```

This is rather counter-intuitive, but "correct": `?` is an order operation, and string has priority over array. Compare:

```
[[1][2][3][4][5]][3]?
["1""2""3""4""5"]"3"?
```

The first gives 2, as expected, but the second gives -1 because the priority of string means that it's searching for the array inside the string - and no array will ever be equal to an int representing a Unicode codepoint. However, these examples do point the way to another approach of reducing the strings to arrays of ints before using approach X.

#### Update

I sent an e-mail to flagitious suggesting a patch and the latest version of Golfscript has new behaviour for `string string ?` and `string array ?`. So if you update, `"ABCDE""C"?` should give `2`.